# How to trigger a button click which is on modal box

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

i have a simple modal box for a form page:

```
$('body').on('click', '#ayarlar', function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal({ 
            overlayClose: true 
        });
        $('#basic-modal-content').load('http://www.myurl.com/inc/pages/islem/genel_ayarlar.php').modal();
        $('body').on('click', '#genel_ayarlar_guncelle', function (e) {
            var pass = $('#adminpass').val();
            var durum = $('#durum').val();
            $.ajax({
               type:"POST",
               url:"http://www.myurl.com/inc/pages/islem/genel_ayarlar_islem.php",
               data: {
                 pass: pass,
                 durum: durum
               },
                success:function(data){
                    $('#basic-modal-content').html(data).modal();
                }                   
            });
        });
        return false;
});
```

I want to trigger #genel_ayarlar_guncelle button's click when pressed enter key but my code doesn't work:

```
$('#adminpass').keypress(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
     $('#genel_ayarlar_guncelle').click();
  }
});
```

I think it must have a simple solution but I am not expert in jquery or simplemodal box of Eric Martin.

Comment: And is `$('#adminpass')` loaded with load() as well ?

Comment: yes it is an input pass in genel_ayarlar.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll guess that the input field is inserted with the `load()` call, as that seems like the only reason it wouldn't work, and then you'll need a delegated event handler

```
$('#basic-modal-content').on('keypress', '#adminpass', function(event){
    if(event.which === 13){
       $('#genel_ayarlar_guncelle').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes this is the answer. 

i'm new at jquery.

I think i need to read handlers, delegating. 

thank you very much.